# Error in application dependency 'sap.m': 'No descriptor was found'

Tags: sapui5, manifest

deploying my application on Fiori launchpad I found the following errors on the console:

```
Error in application dependency 'sap.ui.core': 'No descriptor was found'
Error in application dependency 'sap.m': 'No descriptor was found'
Error in application dependency 'sap.ui.layout': 'No descriptor was found'
```

In the manifest.json file , I declared the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.34.0",
        "libs": {
            "sap.ui.core": {
                "minVersion": "1.34.0"
            },
            "sap.m": {
                "minVersion": "1.34.0"
            },
            "sap.ui.layout": {
                "minVersion": "1.34.0"
            }
        }
    },
```

I don't know what's the problem, could someone help me?
Thanks.

---

The full manifest.json is:

```
 {
    "_version": "1.3.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "_version": "1.3.0",
        "id": "com.roberto",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "sourceTemplate": {
            "id": "ui5template.basicSAPUI5ApplicationProject",
            "version": "1.38.11"
        }
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "_version": "1.3.0",
        "technology": "UI5",
        "deviceTypes": {
            "desktop": true,
            "tablet": true,
            "phone": true
        },
        "supportedThemes": [
            "sap_bluecrystal"
        ]
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "_version": "1.2.0",
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "com.roberto.view.CollectionBoard",
            "type": "XML"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.34.0",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.m": {},
                "sap.ui.layout": {}
            }
        },
        "contentDensities": {
            "compact": false,
            "cozy": true
        },
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "com.roberto.i18n.i18n"
                }
            },
            "CollectionTree": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
                "uri": "model/prdt_collections_tree.json"
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": [
                {
                    "uri": "css/custom.css"
                }
            ]
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewPath": "com.roberto.view",
                "controlId": "collboard",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "bypassed": {
                    "target": "notFound"
                }
            },
            "routes": [
                {
                    "pattern": "",
                    "name": "collections",
                    "target": "TargetCollections"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "detail/{collectionPath}",
                    "name": "RouteDetails",
                    "target": "TargetDetails"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "AddCollection",
                    "name": "RouteAdd",
                    "target": "TargetAdd"
                }
            ],
            "targets": {
                "TargetCollections": {
                    "viewName": "CollectionBoard",
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "viewLevel": 1
                },
                "TargetDetails": {
                    "viewName": "CollectionDetails",
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "viewLevel": 2
                },
                "TargetAdd": {
                    "viewName": "AddCollection",
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "viewLevel": 2
                },
                "notFound": {
                    "viewName": "NotFound",
                    "transition": "show"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sap.platform.hcp": {
        "uri": "webapp",
        "_version": "1.1.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the following somewhere above what you wrote?

```
    "sap.ui": {
    "_version": "1.3.0",
    "technology": "UI5",
    "deviceTypes": {
        "desktop": true,
        "tablet": true,
        "phone": true
    },
    "supportedThemes": [
        "sap_bluecrystal"
    ]
```

Comment: Yes, I did it.. I didn't post the entire manifest.json because I thought it will be verbose. Thanks, for the reply.

Comment: Your manifest.json seems to be ok.
Maybe a silly question: Do you still get this error after clearing your browser cache ?